# Criação de um módulo

Tags: python-3.x, script, módulo-python

Estou com dificuldades na criação do meu próprio módulo. Gostaria de um exemplo com um passo a passo das etapas pra criar um módulo para eu conseguir identificar onde estou errando.

Comment: Que dificuldades? Tudo o que precisa saber para iniciar há na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html), então recomendo que comece lendo-a e, se ainda tiver dúvidas, volte aqui e elabore mais sua pergunta. Possivelmente o guia de [ask] te ajudará a entender melhor como formatar a pergunta.

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Você precisa elaborar a perguntar. Elaborar significa descrever o cenário que você tem com detalhes e colocar o ponto onde há dúvida seguido de tentativas que você já tenha feito.

Comment: Você está tentando executar o seu script? Foi isso que eu entendi e no caso você pode executa-lo pelo terminal (estando no dossier do script): python3 script.py  OU python2 script.py

Comment: Complementando @Anderson com este [link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) . Precisa elaborar um pouco mais a sua pergunta, coloque o código que está a executar.

Comment: Se a dificuldade é usar o Python Interpreter na documentação também possui informações [sobre isso](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html)

Comment: Editei novamente a pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você parece estar confuso com relação ao uso do import direto no interpretador *vs* a execução de um arquivo `.py` com imports dentro dele. Sem o código fica difícil entender onde você está errando, mas vou partir do ponto que leu a documentação de módulos do python e não entendeu.

No tutorial do site ele está usando direto o interpretador. Lá, tudo que ele importar estará disponível para ser usado nos próximos comandos do interpretador e apenas dele.

Porém, entendo que você quer importar e executar em um arquivo separado. Usando o exemplo da [própria documentação](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html), você pode [conferir aqui](https://repl.it/repls/JoyousUntidyCopycat) como ficaria um aplicativo em python usando módulo.

Explicando o código, o arquivo `fibo.py` fornece as funções para cálculo da sequência de fibonacci que o arquivo `main.py` (mostrado a seguir) utilizará:

```
# Fibonacci numbers module

def fib2(n):   # return Fibonacci series up to n
    result = []
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        result.append(b)
        a, b = b, a+b
    return result
```

Arquivo `main.py` será usado como o arquivo principal, para iniciar sua aplicação em python, importando o módulo que precisa:

```
from fibo import fib2

print(fib2(100))
```

Veja que o nome do arquivo (`fibo`) é o nome do próprio módulo.

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que você queira colocar suas rotinas dentro de um arquivo separado. Por exemplo você tem a rotina `media()` no seu programa:

```
def media(a,b):
    return (a+b)/2.0

print(media(4,2))
```

Então você coloca em um arquivo separado, o "modulos.py" e edita seu programa principal para:

```
from modulos import media

print(media(4,2))
```

Desejando acrescentar mais funções ao "modulos.py", basta fazê-lo:

```
def media(a,b):
    return (a+b)/2.0

def maior(a,b):
    return a if a>b else b
```

E daí editar seu programa para carregar as funções que precisa:

```
from modulos import media, maior
```

Ou então carregar todas as funções disponíveis dentro dele:

```
from modulos import *
```

Claro, este é um exemplo simples de módulos com todos os arquivos estando no mesmo diretório.